# How can I get these images to sit side by side in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I can't get them to sit side by side. Been chasing my tail for 2 days now with lots of googling but no luck.

```js
        <Column1>
              <TextWrapper>  
                <TopLine>{topLine}</TopLine>
                <Heading lightText={lightText}>{headline}</Heading>
                <Subtitle darkText={darkText}>{description}</Subtitle>
                <ImgWrap>
              <a href="https://arabic.cnn.com/style/article/2018/08/15/egypt-marwan-shahin"><Img src={img7} alt={alt}/></a>
              <a href="https://designmuseum.org/exhibitions/hope-to-nope-graphics-and-politics-2008-18/qa-with-marwan-shahin#"><Img src={img8} alt={alt}/></a>
              <a href="https://www.egypttoday.com/Article/4/3074/Artist-Of-The-Month-Marwan-Shahin"><Img src={img9} alt={alt}/></a>
              </ImgWrap>
              </TextWrapper> 
            </Column1>
```

[trying to get these side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE3up.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using CSS. Display the container as Flex. This will allow you to display it side by side. Also set some margin, width and height for individual images.